# Weak convergence (in the context of Hilbert spaces) of sqaure integrable random variables.

Tags: random-variables, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and consider the Hilbert space

$$\mathcal{X}:=\{X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}~\mbox{measurable}: \mathbb{E}[X^2]<\infty\}$$

with scalar product $(X,Y)=E[XY]$. What does it mean for a sequence of random variables to converge weakly in the Hilbert space setting? I.e., a sequence $X_1,X_2,...$ is said to converge weakly to $X$, if $\mathbb{E}[X_n Y] = (X_n,Y) \to (X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]$ for all $Y\in\mathcal{X}$.  E.g., assume that $X_1,X_2,... \subset \mathcal{X}$ are i.i.d, what is its weak limit? Since $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]<\infty$ the sequence is bounded in $\mathcal{X}$, thus there exists at least a convergent subsequence... I would expect something deterministic like $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ as the weak limit, is this correct? My intuition was that this holds true for all $Z$ independent of $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ and so maybe for general $Z$ there holds some kind of asymptotically independence.

Anyway, could someone comment on the use of the concept of Hilbert space weak convergence for square-integrable random variables? I have rarely seen it...